# No Wifi On Linuxt Mint 21.1 On MSI Raider GE76

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, wifi

I have a problem with Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon on MSI Raider GE76, I cannot find the icon to connect to WIFI.

Here's some output of some commands to help understand my problem:

```
inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.5 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Raider GE76 12UHS v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-17K4 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E17K4IMS.208 date: 06/06/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 88.6 Wh (95.8%) condition: 92.5/95.0 Wh (97.3%)
    volts: 16.4 min: 15.2 model: MSI BIF0_9 status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900HK bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 1.2 MiB L2: 11.5 MiB
    L3: 24 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 429 high: 494 min/max: 400/5000:3800 cores: 1: 443
    2: 420 3: 428 4: 421 5: 458 6: 494 7: 485 8: 483 9: 426 10: 422 11: 486
    12: 419 13: 400 14: 400 15: 400 16: 400 17: 400 18: 400 19: 400 20: 400
    bogomips: 116736
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA103M [GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Mobile] vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-7:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.60.11 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi vendor: Rivet Networks
    driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:14.3
  Device-2: Realtek Killer E3000 2.5GbE vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus-ID: 2f:00.0
  IF: enp47s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:7
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.86 TiB used: 22.67 GiB (1.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVL22T0HBLB-00B00
    size: 1.86 TiB temp: 43.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 617.53 GiB used: 22.64 GiB (3.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 296 MiB used: 32.8 MiB (11.1%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 42 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 391 Uptime: 3m Memory: 62.57 GiB used: 2.4 GiB (3.8%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 2226 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13



rfkill list && mokutil --sb-state
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
SecureBoot disabled

sudo dmesg | grep iwl

iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1672, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

Linux Mint is installed as Dual Boot with Windows 11
PS: I already disabled Fast Boot and Hibernates on Windows 11

As you can see there is no driver installed for the WIFI card and the Driver Manager not showing any driver related to install.

Can any one please help me fix this problem ?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output for `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Done, hope it's helpful

Comment: Try kernel 6.1.3.

Comment: could you please show me how or give me a link on how to do it ? the update manager program does not show any update of kernel

Comment: Google: how to install kernel X in Distro_name, e.g. how to install kernel 6.1 in Linux Mint. They also have their own forums with a pretty active community.

Comment: I fixed the problem by doing this ```sudo apt-get install linux-oem-22.04```

Comment: A new kernel, OK.

Comment: Thank you for your help